# Total Gini impurity or entropy gain for a scikit-learn decision tree

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tree, entropy

How can I get the total weighted Gini impurity (or entropy) on a trained decision tree in scikit-learn? For instance, the following code on the titanic dataset,

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import tree
df_titanic = pd.read_csv('titanic_data.csv')    # a popular dataset
feat_list = ['SibSp','Pclass']  # number of siblings and spouses aboard; passenger class (1st,2nd,3rd)
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(df_titanic.loc[:,feat_list],df_titanic['Survived'])
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
tree.plot_tree(clf,feature_names=feat_list,class_names=['NS','S'])
fig.show()
```

produces a tree with leaves with gini impurity values and sample sizes of (no particular order) (0.378,71), (0.32,5), (0.5,8),... I'm interested in the weighted sum, 0.378(71/891) + 0.32(5/891) + 0.5(8/891) + ... where 891 is the total number of samples (passengers). What's an easy way to do this?

I'd like to compare the total Gini impurity (or entropy) before and after the tree is constructed (as in Provost and Fawcett), but after researching the docs a bit there doesn't seem to be a tree attribute or method that directly produces this info.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing--to continue with the example in the question posting:

```
# determine starting gini impurity (without any decision tree)
surv_clss = df_titanic['Survived'][:]   # 0=did not survive; 1=survived
p_0 = sum((surv_clss==0))/len(surv_clss)
gini_start = 1-(p_0**2+(1-p_0)**2)
print("impurity before: %s" % gini_start)

# get leaf node indices
leaf_nodes_by_sample = clf.apply(df_titanic.loc[:,feat_list]) # .apply gets the
# leaf node each sample belongs to
leaf_nodes = np.unique(leaf_nodes_per_sample)

# determine total gini impurity of decision tree (weighted average)
tot_imp = 0.0
num_sam = len(df_titanic.index)
for node in leaf_nodes:
    nd_ct = clf.tree_.n_node_samples[node]  # num samples at 'node'
    tot_imp += (nd_ct/num_sam)*clf.tree_.impurity[node] # gini impurity at 'node'

print("average weighted impurity after the tree: %s" % tot_imp)
```

For the docs on navigating a decision tree and getting its properties, see https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_unveil_tree_structure.html.

This works, but, again, I thought there might be an easier way(?)